# Validate Access Token on resource server

Tags: node.js, react-native, api, access-token

I'm new to this site, so please go easy on me.

I'm building a mobile app in React Native and for the backend I'm working in nodejs. I've created Auth server which sends back access and refresh tokens on authentication.

Now I would like to validate the bearer token on the resource server. But I've no idea how to verify the access token is valid or not. How do I check whether the access token is a valid one?

I would be grateful if someone could shed some light on this post. Thank you.

I'm willing to provide more info if I'm unclear about my question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are creating the access tokens?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 technical mechanisms for.an API to validate an access token:

- Get token signing keys and verify the signature of the access token
- Send the access token to the Authorization Server's introspection endpoint

In total you check these things are correct:

- Signature
- Issuer
- Audience
- Expiry

The first of these is more commonly used, though I prefer the second option.

**RESOURCES OF MINE**

- [Signature Validation NodeJS Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- [Introspection NodeJS Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- [Validation Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/06/azure-ad-api-token-validation/)

Comment: The usual way of dealing with that is to combine it with [Claims Caching](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) so that introspection only occurs when a token is first received by the resource server.

Comment: That makes sense .. thank you. But the access tokens expires after some time.. so, we have to repeat the caching for fresh access tokens?

Comment: I've read the entire blog post, that's all I want to know.